# Resouce not found when accessing Saml2 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sustainsys-saml2

I tried to setup SAML2 for our ASP.net MVC web application. Followed the guide on the official documentation (https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/) . But when i access the controller it is showing 
"The resource cannot be found. " None of the Saml2 Controller action works.

http://localhost:63856/Saml2/

I tried setting up a web forms application. Loaded the httpmodule and got no problem. I tried to load the httpmodule(which apparently shouldnt be loaded in an MVC app), the saml2 action works but it is giving an invalid response for some reason.

i set this up in configsection

```
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="sustainsys.saml2" type="Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SustainsysSaml2Section, Sustainsys.Saml2"/>
```

Added this in Module

```
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
```

and added the main config

```
 <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xx" returnUrl="https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xx/Sso/Authenticate" authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Always">
      <serviceCertificates>

        <add fileName="C:\xxxx.pfx" use="Signing" />

      </serviceCertificates>

      <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx" signOnUrl="https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xx"  allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
          <signingCertificate fileName="C:\tmp\xxxxxxx.crt" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
  </sustainsys.saml2>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="DCMAuth"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

When i access 
 http://localhost:63856/Saml2/

without the HttpModule. it gives

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Saml2/

But when i load HttpModule. it gives an invalid response.

Am i missing something ? ONly Sustainsys.web.mvc is reference in my main project.

Comment: Do you have any custom routing configuration? The guide assumes that you are using the default convention based routing.

Comment: @AndersAbel yes. im using the default router. issue is same as this one i think https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/268 .

Comment: @AndersAbel by the way. i was able to make the HttpModule work on my MVC app. not sure what the problem was. but since we have tight deadline i will leave the httpModule sitting there for a while. thank for your response.

Comment: Using the http module in an mvc is perfectly fine, just remember to remove the mvc package. Having both loaded can lead to conflicts.